# Magento 2 : How to Get Product ID After Event

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer

When I click on 'proceed-to-checkout', it start `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index` event.
I tried with `Zend_Debug::dump($observer->getProduct()->getId());`
 but it doesn't work.

Do you have some tips?

Thanks

Comment: hey can you try to get product from cart on your observer?

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have try this and work fine for me.

```
class Produt implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
    {
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {

    $product = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($product as $pro){
        echo $pro->getId();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Where are these data stored ? In cookies or database ?